# Can the Nullstellensatz over $\mathbb{C}^n$ be certified by repeatedly guessing witnesses in $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-complexity

In [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is in the Polynomial Hierarchy](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d4e6/87c5dc96a0e4fd47465792f7b6f694a85e7a.pdf), P. Koiran showed that, given a system of $S$ of $m$ polynomials on $n$ variables of maximum degree $d$, along with a number $x_0$ exponential in $m,n,d$, whether or not

$$f_1[x_1,\cdots,x_n]=\cdots=f_m[x_1,\cdots,x_n]=0\:\:\:(*)$$

with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}^n$, depends on the number $\pi_S(x_0)$ of primes $\le x_0$ modulo which there's a solution.

In more detail, if $(*)$ *does not* have a solution in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then the number $\pi_S(x_0)$ of primes $p$ such that there is a witness $\bar{w}=(\bar{x}_1,\cdots,\bar{x}_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $f_1[\bar{x}_1,\cdots,\bar{x}_n]=\cdots=f_m[\bar{x}_1,\cdots,\bar{x}_n]=0$ modulo $p$ is $\le A$ for some number $A$ exponential in $m,n,d$.

However.  if $(*)$ *does* have a solution in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then (assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis), the number $\pi_S(x_0)$ is $\ge B=8A\text{log}(A+3)$.

In general, although there may be a *finite* number of primes modulo which $(*)$ is satisfiable if $(*)$ is not satisfiable in $\mathbb{C}$, and an *infinite* number of primes modulo which $(*)$ is satisfied if $(*)$ is satisfiable in $\mathbb{C}$,  in the latter case the density of primes modulo which a solution exists, by the [Chebotariv density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem), is $\frac{|C|}{|G|}$, where $G$ is the Galois group of $f$ and $C$ is the set of permutations $g\in G$ which have at least one fixed point.

One of Koiran's insights is that because there's enough of a gap $A$ between and $B$, he can use *universal hashing* for his algorithm.  Specifically, the first algorithm that Koiran proposes is to utilize a good random hash $H$ onto a set of size $B$ to find a prime $\hat{p}$ such that *both* $H(\hat{p})=0$ *and* there's a witness $\hat{w}=(\hat{x}_1,\cdots,\hat{x_n})$ with $f_1[\hat{x}_1,\cdots,\hat{x}_n]=\cdots=f_m[\hat{x}_1,\cdots,\hat{x}_n]=0$ modulo $\hat{p}$.

The two requirements - finding a $\hat{p}$ that hashes on to $0$, *and* a $\hat{w}$ such that $(*)$ is satisfied modulo $\hat{p}$ - seem difficult independent problems.  I can look for a prime whose hash is $0$, and then I have to find a witness to $(*)$ modulo that prime.  Although hashing a prime is easy, finding a prime that hashes onto $0$ is exponentially difficult, and further still, finding a witness such that $(*)$ is satisfied modulo the hashed prime feels like solving a difficult $\mathsf{SAT}$ problem.  Thus, the complexity seems like two exponentially difficult problems.

However, I suspect that this is, in a certain sense, reversible - that is, I can guess a witness *prior* to hashing.

> Given the above setup, instead of first finding a $\hat{p}$ such that $H(\hat{p})=0$ and then finding a witness $\hat{w}$ such that $(*)$ is satisfied modulo $\hat{p}$, would it be more efficient if we were to instead look for putative witnesses $\tilde{w}=(\tilde{x}_1,\cdots,\tilde{x}_n)$ such that $H(\gcd(f_1(\tilde{w}), \cdots, f_m(\tilde{w}))=0$?

Calculating $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ is easy.  Euclid's algorithm suffices to calculate the $\gcd$.  And calculating the hash is easy.  If the hash isn't $0$, guess another witness $\tilde{w}$.  There's no $\mathsf{SAT}$ problem to solve, as there would be if we found $\hat{p}$ before finding $\hat{w}$.

The $\gcd$ of most witnesses is probably $1$.  However, if $(*)$ is satisfied in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then the same $\hat{p}$ I would find with the first algorithm would, I believe, be a $\gcd(f(\tilde{w}))$ that I could eventually find.

Comment: I'm a little confused - if (*) _does_ have a solution $w$, then isn't $\pi_S$ just the set of _all_ primes?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thanks for your question.  $\pi_S$ may be infinite, but the density may be exponentially small.  Koiran gave the example $S$ of 
$$x^p=1$$
$$y(x-1)=1$$
There are $p-1$ solutions over $\mathbb{C}$.  However, Koiran shows that the density of primes modulo which there is a solution is $1/(p-1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see - I was thinking over $\mathbb{N}$ (well, $\mathbb{N}^n$), not $\mathbb{C}^n$. That makes a lot more sense; thank you!

Comment: 1. The Nullstellensatz is a theorem, not a problem to be solved. In your title, do you mean rather "Can the Nullstellensatz be certified" or "witnessed"? 2. Your question seems to be "Can I do the following thing", to which the answer is yes, go for it. But perhaps you mean to ask a different question? What exactly are you trying to find out? Are you asking for an estimate of the efficiency of this approach? Ways to make it more efficient?

Comment: @ZachTeitler: in the context of complexity and algorithms, we often refer to the "computational problem Hilbert's Nullstellensatz" as the problem of deciding whether a given system of integer polynomial equations has a complex root. Obviously we also refer to the theorem as the Nullstellensatz, just like everyone else, but in context this typically never leads to confusion. The OP is asking about a potential improvement to Koiran's algorithm, so obviously the question is about the complexity of the proposed algorithm.

Comment: Hmm. Hashing the gcd of the values $f_i(\hat w)$ is a little odd. The more obvious (not necessarily smart) thing to do would be to hash each prime factor of the gcd—if one of those prime factors hashes to $0$, you've found $\hat p$. But that involves factoring. ... I guess, how does it help that the gcd hashes to $0$, if the gcd is composite? Would you do a primality test and only check the hash when the gcd is prime?

Comment: @ZachTeitler, thanks for taking the time to understand my question- and great comment!  I wonder if, assuming GRH, one could heuristically argue that there should be *more* candidate gcd's for systems of polynomial equations with solutions over $\mathbb{C}^n$ than for those without solutions.  Or, if not, one could say that such gcd's are at best likely to be (small primes)x(one big prime), in which case your factoring idea is not so bad.  Or, only hashing gcd's when the gcd *is* a prime is probably still a winner, by the PNT?

Comment: Good questions! Unfortunately this is far beyond my knowledge of number theory. I just hope my naive comments helped sharpen and focus your question. At this point, hopefully someone who knows will step in. Good luck!